# drupal_write_records() doesn’t work for those fields which was created by hook_update_n()

Tags: drupal

Currently i have created table using install schema in drupal 7. After that the table is alter to add new column using hook_update_n().

now the drupal_write_records() doesn’t work for 
those fields which was created by hook_update_n().

Regards,
Raj.

Answer (score 2):

**hook_schema** or **hook_update_N**?

Drupal provides a very powerful and structured way of upgrading your sites and making DDIC changes. The two important hooks are hook_schema() provides a structured, DB independent way of defining you table schema. When a new module is installed, the hook_schema() is automatically invoked (yes that's the case in Drupal 7, while in Drupal 6 it had to be explicitly used to create tables) and the tables are created.

Now that your tables are created and module is being used, you decide to do a change in the table, let's say you decided to add a new field. Now how will this change reach all the system and upgrade seamlessly so that the module / code depending on this field does not break.

Drupal provides another hook called hook_update_N() where N is a numerical value indicating the version of schema e.g. mymodule_update_1() for the first change and mymodule_update_2() for the second change and so on. Coming back to our example, suppose you need to add a new field, you'll need to implement the hook as follows

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 */ 
function mymodule_update_1() {
  db_add_field('mytable', 'myfield', array(
    'description' => 'My Status Field',
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'unsigned' => FALSE,
  ));
}
```

Once this is done, the update has to be run using either drush updb or via the url /update.php. Once the update is run, Drupal recognizes that there is an update in schema since the number 1 (from the above example) was never run. It runs the function and tracks that the version of schema as 1. So the next time you make another change and need to update the table schema you can use any number higher than the previous maximum number and Drupal will apply that change.

Now is the change in hook_update_N() sufficient? The answer is No, you need to update the hook_schema() for the appropriate table. For two reasons
    1. When you run any query after this, Drupal will not find the new field in the table schema definition and thus will not write this field e.g. when using drupal_write_record().
    2. When the module is installed in a new site that never had this module before, Drupal will only run the hook_schema() and does not run any other updates as it expects the table schema
    is up-to-date and stores the schema version as the highest hook_update_N() number. Only changed after this will be applied when update is run.

**Conclusion**

Appropriate table schema must be updated in the hook_schemea().
Next perform the database update using hook_update_N(), where N > pervious max update number

Comment: Very helpful! This helped me a lot why it's not updating.